# How to have 2 functions call each other in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I want to have 2 different recursive functions in OCaml, where each 1 could call the other one. It isn't working because the one that is declared 1st isn't able to call the one that is declared 2nd. Is there any way to make it work without combining the two functions into 1?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what `and` is for:

```
let rec f x = if x < 2 then 1 else x * g (x - 1)
and g x = if x < 2 then 1 else x * f (x - 1)
```